# Wordpress. When there are NO search results, MENU items disapear from TOP MENU

Tags: wordpress, search, menu

I am experiencing a strange problem and can't find anything even similar to a solution.

I am using wp_bootstrap_navwalker to implement a main top menu in a custom WordPress theme.

The menu works well but I noticed something odd. When I search for something, when I land on search results page, IF there are no results, the items from the menu disappear as well.

I do get the menu structure WITH href="intended-url" but in place of anchor text I can only see a RIGHT ARROW..

This does not happen if search results exist.

If you go to this page bite4joy.com/?s=unicorn this would be the problem as i describe it,,, If you go to home page or any other page that contains content the menu appears alright. I noticed the category pages suffer from this problem when there is no content also.

Can you suggest at least a beginning of a solution?

Comment: Any way we could see this online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoa. Very interesting.

So first, I see this is in the source code of your page, which means it's done server-side, not through javascript.

I don't see anything in the wp_bootstrap_navwalker that would do this either. So I think it's something else.

The one thing I can think of is `the_title` filter: try to see if you can find

> add_filter('the_title'

or

> add_filter("the_title"

in any of your plugin or theme files (do a cross-file search) and see if any one outputs the arrow (or it's HTMLL equivalent →)

Hope this helps a little bit...

Good luck!

Comment: Definitely not navwalker. You are right. I just tested without navwalker and I get the same behavior,, I will look into the_title :)

Comment: I found a filter that was doing this,, when I remove the filter all together I get the same result except with blank spaces,, lol,, weird

Comment: Wo - ok. Well, then my guess is something *else* is also using the `the_title` filter...?

Comment: It came down to a plugin

Comment: Sweet - at least you fond the problem. Hope you didn't absolutely need that plugin! ;)

Comment: I absolutely need it,, lol,, but I found where in the plugin it happens and I modified it (for now)